# How to escape & operator in URL bulding

Tags: javascript, struts2

I am facing a problem in building URL in javaScript

here is my code

```
function sectionLink(cellvalue,options,rowObject)
 {

    return "<a href='somesAction?DptCode="+rowObject['deptCode']+"&viewName="+rowObject['_name']+"'>View</a>" ;

}
```

Here is my problem .. if `DptCode`  is having `&` symbol in that string, I can access only half string i mean before that `&` symbol.

For example `DptCode=Hero&Heroin` in this case In my action class I can get only `Hero` so is there any way to escape this `&` symbol in my string .. I am using struts 2, jQ-Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are taking the variable from `GET`.

When `GET` parameters are received, spliting is done on the basis of `&`, so you need to escape them in JavaScript with [encodeURIComponent(str);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)